# Protractor iOS Automation: A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow

Tags: javascript, ios, jasmine, protractor, appium

I am using Protractor @1.7.0 and appium to automate an iOS Hybrid app. I am getting Timeout error all the time while executing the tests. 
Kindly Advise.

**Config.js**

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 50000 ,
getPageTimeout: 50000 ,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
specs: ['PageObjectSpec.js'],
capabilities: {
browserName: 'iOS' ,
'appium-version':'1.3.4',
platformName:'iOS' ,
platformVersion: 7.1 ,
deviceName:'iPhone' ,
autoWebview:true , 
},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100',

jasmineNodeOpts: {showColors: true, defaultTimeoutInterval:50000} ,
};
```

**TestSpec.js:**

```
'use strict';
describe('Abbvie app test', function()

{
var userName = element(by.model('credentials.username'));

var passwd = element(by.model('credentials.password'));
var signin = element(by.buttonText('Sign In'));
var name="patientqq" ;
var pass="Healthy1" ;

it('Login Page test', function()
{
userName.click()
userName.sendKeys(name)

passwd.click()
passwd.sendKeys(pass)
signin.click()

});
});
```

**Protractor logs:**

```
    Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 
Protractor.waitForAngular()
at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:345:15)
at [object Object].Protractor.executeAsyncScript_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:251:26)
at [object Object].Protractor.waitForAngular (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:274:15)
at [object Object].getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:136:19)
at [object Object].getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:669:31)
at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:391:28)
at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) as click
at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) as click
at [object Object]. (/Users/qualcomm/Desktop/ProtractorTest/PageObjectSpec.js:13:11)
F

Failures:

1) Abbvie app test Login Page test
Message:
timeout: timed out after 50000 msec waiting for spec to complete
Stacktrace:
undefined

Finished in 57.396 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] iOS #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

**Appium Logs:**

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.

```
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}
info: [debug] Setting auto webview
info: [debug] Waiting for 4000 ms before navigating to view.

info: [debug] Navigating to most recently opened webview

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Getting WebKitRemoteDebugger pageArray

info: [debug] Picking webview WEBVIEW_1

info: [debug] Attempting to set context to 'WEBVIEW_1'
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger web socket connected to url [ws://localhost:27753/devtools/page/1]
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Unregistering from page readiness notifications
info: [debug] Waiting for app source to contain elements
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:43 +0000 Debug: Running system command #2: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:48 +0000 Debug: Got new command 2 from instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:48 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:48 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:48 +0000 Debug: responding with:ull,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAScrollView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAWebView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[]}},{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0/1","x":316.5,"y":0,"width":3.5,"height":568},">":[]}},{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0/2","x":0,"y":564.5,"width":320,"height":3.5},">":[]}}]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAStatusBar":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":20},">":[{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"No SIM","label":"No SIM","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/0","x":6,"y":0,"width":42,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","label":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","value":"SPAN-GENERAL","dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/1","x":53,"y":0,"width":13,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"7:39 pm","label":"7:39 pm","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/2","x":137,"y":0,"width":46,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"100% battery power, On AC Power","label":"100% battery power, On AC Power","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/3","x":248,"y":0,"width":67,"height":20},">":[]}}]}}]}}]}}}
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:48 +0000 Debug: Running system command #3: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"AbbVie Care Global","label":"AbbVie Care Global...

info: [debug] Socket data received (3021 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"AbbVie Care Global","label":"AbbVie Care Global","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":548},">":[{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":n
info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 7200 secs
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 12286.856 ms - 9

info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8 {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"iOS","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"iOS","appium-version":"1.3.4","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":7.1,"deviceName":"iPhone","autoWebview":true,"count":1},"appium-version":"1.3.4","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":7.1,"deviceName":"iPhone","autoWebview":true,"count":1},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8 200 6.085 ms - 556 {"status":0,"value":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"iOS","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"iOS","appium-version":"1.3.4","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":7.1,"deviceName":"iPhone","autoWebview":true,"count":1},"appium-version":"1.3.4","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":7.1,"deviceName":"iPhone","autoWebview":true,"count":1},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8/timeouts/async_script {"ms":50000}

info: [debug] Set iOS async script timeout to 50000ms
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8/timeouts/async_script 200 6.598 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8/execute_async {"script":"try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {\n var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n\n try {\n if (!window.angular) {\n throw new Error('angular could not be found on the window');\n }\n if (angular.getTestability) {\n angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);\n } else {\n if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +\n ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');\n }\n angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').\n notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);\n }\n } catch (err) {\n callback(err.message);\n }\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":["body"]}

info: [debug] Response url for executeAsync is http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8/receive_async_response

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Remote debugger data sent [{"method":"Runtime.evaluate","params":{"objectGroup":"console","includeCommandLineAPI":true,"doNotPauseOnExceptionsAndMuteConsole":true,"expression":"(function(){return function(){var l=this;\nfunctio...]

Debugger web socket received data : {"result":{"result":{"type":"undefined"},"wasThrown":false},"id":1}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert

info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:54 +0000 Debug: Got new command 3 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:54 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:55 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:55 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-12 14:09:55 +0000 Debug: Running system command #4: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:56 +0000 Debug: Got new command 4 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:56 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:56 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:56 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:56 +0000 Debug: Running system command #5: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:57 +0000 Debug: Got new command 5 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:57 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:57 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:57 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:57 +0000 Debug: Running system command #6: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:58 +0000 Debug: Got new command 6 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:58 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:58 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:58 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:58 +0000 Debug: Running system command #7: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:59 +0000 Debug: Got new command 7 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:59 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
2015-03-12 14:09:59 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:59 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:09:59 +0000 Debug: Running system command #8: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}
info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:00 +0000 Debug: Got new command 8 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:00 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:00 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:00 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-12 14:10:00 +0000 Debug: Running system command #9: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:01 +0000 Debug: Got new command 9 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:01 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
2015-03-12 14:10:01 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
2015-03-12 14:10:01 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:01 +0000 Debug: Running system command #10: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:02 +0000 Debug: Got new command 10 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:02 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()
2015-03-12 14:10:02 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
2015-03-12 14:10:02 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:02 +0000 Debug: Running system command #11: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:03 +0000 Debug: Got new command 11 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:03 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:03 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:03 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-12 14:10:03 +0000 Debug: Running system command #12: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:04 +0000 Debug: Got new command 12 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:04 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:04 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:04 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:04 +0000 Debug: Running system command #13: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: [debug] atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:05 +0000 Debug: Got new command 13 from instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:05 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.alertIsPresent()

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:05 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:10:05 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-12 14:10:05 +0000 Debug: Running system command #14: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (28 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":false}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 5.238 ms - 178 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 5.005 ms - 178 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.5","revision":"a124a15677e26b33db16e81c4b3b34d9c6b8cac9"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8 {}

info: Shutting down appium session
info: [debug] Stopping ios
info: [debug] Destroying instruments client socket.
info: [debug] Closing socket server.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server was closed
info: [debug] Sending sigterm to instruments

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-12 14:11:41 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 12 19:40:46 iPhone com.apple.launchd1 : (UIKitApplication:com.span.sampleTest[0x7dca]) Exited: Killed: 9

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 12 19:40:46 iPhone backboardd[31] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.span.sampleTest[0x7dca]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 12 19:40:47 iPhone DTPower[185] : Task info failed for task com.span.sampleTest

info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 67.278687s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0

info: [debug] Cleaning up after instruments exit
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Disconnecting from remote debugger

info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}

info: <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8 200 843.700 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/fc13cf29-cd3e-43cc-8ad3-5efbfbee6cf8/execute_async - - ms - -
```

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Same issue here. I think it has something to do with this message that's getting repeated a bunch of times: "atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert". For me this starts after the first test is finished. There's no alert, everything looks normal in the simulator. Perhaps something unintended happens after test, it's not able to find the right context and times out?

Comment: after a year I've hit same problem and looking for help here...

Answer (score 1):

I feel that protractor is trying to wait for angular to be present on your page. If you are not using angular in your page, you can turn it off, so that protractor can then run the test scripts without waiting for angular to settle. Here's how to do it. Update your **conf.js** file `onPrepare()` function to include `ignoreSynchronization` globally so that you don't have to ignore it for all the test scripts -

```
onPrepare: function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
```

Or declare `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in your test suite, which will be applicable for that test suite only. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think the key lies in understanding the cause of this repeated message in the logs: "atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert"